# Using a Math Library in the iOS View Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, shared-libraries, categories

I am creating a view controller for a calculator view. This calculator requires the use of a lot of heavy duty financial math. I encapsulated most of the calculations into a few functions, should these functions be left in the view controller or should I create a separate library and use them there?

If I do create a separate library, do I connect it using #import or do I use Objective-C categories?

Comment: you should create a seperate class and put the methods there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate library is not required. 
However, according to Model-View-Controller design pattern, you should create new class and place your math methods/objects there